# error en tapply dentro de una función

Tags: r

Quiero usar tapply dentro de una función para que esta pueda reproducir diferentes tests de diferentes variables del data frame como se reproduce en el ejemplo ↓↓.

Cuando hago un tapply con el df y sus dos variables me da un resultado, pero cuando hago lo mismo, dentro de una función me sale error:

*Error in split.default(X, group) : first argument must be a vector*

```
#dataframe:    
ALA_plu_any<-data.frame( Any=c("X1995", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2011", "X1995", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X2006", "X2007", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2015", "X1995", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", "X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", "X2012", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999"), Pluviometria=c(999, 1167, 746, 476, 862.5, 604, 1094.5, 845, 844, 750, 560, 437.7, 1027, 969, 1020.6, 570, 1027, 586.2, 513.4, 649.4, 522.1, 768.6, 624, 551.2, 519.8, 505.6, 440.6, 787.1, 596.6, 780.9, 825.2, 467.8, 640.5, 787.3, 503, 581, 478, 636, 662, 905.3, 466.6, 20.4, 476.4, 618.9, 1183, 627.9, 580, 691.6, 557.1, 869.2, 716.7, 587.8, 592.9, 528.6, 465.3, 874.5, 634.2, 801, 846.3, 487.6, 575.4, 787.7, 411.6, 849.5, 838.5, 632.5, 582.5, 550, 516, 900.5, 643.5, 734.7, 807.9, 495.6, 738.3, 860.3, 410.8, 1268, 778, 781.5, 781.5, 600, 1015, 895.5, 762, 783, 704, 547, 1091.5, 743.5, 916.5, 1035.1, 614.3, 998.7, 1066.9, 696.7, 1558, 787.5, 836.5, 820))



  getwd()
#dafra = dataframe ; fact1 y fact 2= factores ; tesT = test
trest <- function(dafra, fact1, fact2, tesT){
  tttt<-tapply(dafra$fact1, dafra$fact2, tesT)
  return(tttt)
}

tapply(ALA_plu_any$Pluviometria, ALA_plu_any$Any, shapiro.test)
#correcto

TTT <- trest(ALA_plu_any, Pluviometria, Any, chisq.test)
#da error
```

Comment: Hola @JosepA. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Decir "el `tapply` me falla" es un poco genérico. ¿podrías explicar con más detalle qué es lo que falla? Intenta que alguien que quiere ayudarte y lee tu pregunta pueda tener un indicio sobre qué enfocarse. ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado? ¿Qué estás obteniendo ahora? ¿Hay algún mensaje de error? ¿Cuál? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]... Luego sería genial si pudieses [edit] la pregunta para hacerla más clara.

Comment: Te recomendaría usar el paquete plyr o dplyr. Te va a ser más sencillo y mucho menos código.

Comment: gracias señores. El script final: `trest <- function(fact1, fact2, tesT, chr_var1, chr_var2, chr_test) {
          tttt<-tapply(fact1, fact2, tesT)
          TUT <- as.data.frame(sapply(tttt, "[[", 'p.value'))
          cc1<-paste(as.character(chr_test),"_", as.character(chr_var1),"_",as.character(chr_var2),"_pvalor", collapse="_", sep="")
          colnames(TUT)<-c(cc1)
          return(TUT)
        }
        `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No haces lo mismo en los dos lados. En tu función no puedes pasar las columnas como lo haces.

¿Algo así no te vale?

```
trest <- function(fact1, fact2, tesT) {
    tttt<-tapply(fact1, fact2, tesT)
    return(tttt)
}

trest(ALA_plu_any$Pluviometria, ALA_plu_any$Any, chisq.test)
```

Comment: Me vale! gracias.

Comment: Hola @JosepA Si te ha ayudado la respuesta, ¿podrías votarla? También puedes marcarla como aceptada. Ver: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
¡También puedes agregar **tu respuesta** y marcarla como respondida!

Comment: Gracias Hernan por tu consideración

Answer (score 1):

Se puede resolver utilizando la familia de paquetes `tidyverse`, en particular los paquetes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

ALA_plu_any %>% 
  nest(-Any) %>%
  mutate(shap = purrr::map(data, ~ shapiro.test(.$Pluviometria))) %>% 
  unnest(map(shap, tidy)) %>% 
  select(-c(data, shap, method))
```

`dplyr::nest` para agrupar los datos. Al poner como argumento `-Any`, agrupa según esa variable. Genera un `dataframe` que tiene dos columnas en este caso:

- `Any`: Una columna con cada nivel que toma la variable `Any` (`factor`).
- `data`: Una columna formada por `dataframe`s. Para cada valor de `Any`, va a existir un `dataframe` asociado que contenga como única columna `Pluviometria` y como filas todos los valores que toma la variable `Pluvometria` para ese nivel de `Any` en el `dataset` original.

`purrr::map` para cada elemento de `data`, aplica `shapire.test` a la columna `Pluviometria`.

`broom::tidy` construye un `dataframe` donde resume los resultados que surgen del `shapire.test`, en este caso muestra el valor del estadístico y el **p-valor**.

En el último paso sólo saco las columnas de los cálculos intermedios.

Comment: Gracias por su consideración